# window.scroll not working on all Browsers in localhost using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I ve the following working in codepen but not localy

https://codepen.io/LoudDesignStudios/pen/RwxPJKY

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/css1.css">
</head>
<body>
<section id="about-us" class="">
s1
</section>
<section id="why-choose-us" class="">
s2
</section>
<section id="funfacts" class="">
s3
</section>
<section id="services" class="">
s4
</section>
<section id="studio" class="">
s5    
</section>
<section id="contactus" class="">
  s6    
</section>
<section id="footer-widgets" class="">
 s7       
</section>
<footer id="footer" class="footer">
  footer      
</footer>
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="scrollUp"><i class="las la-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<script>
var mybutton = document.getElementById("scrollUp");
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 60 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 60) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Same codes working in other websites made a while ago and still working just starting from scratch now the window.scroll is not firing.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the typo of your script tag not being closed properly only in the example you provided here?

Comment: yes only here was pasting and made that mistake

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to get an element (`mybutton`) by its ID before the document's contents are fully loaded.

You will need to wrap your code inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler. Below is slightly modified version of your JavaScript code:

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      var mybutton = document.getElementById("scrollUp");
      window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };

      function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 60 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 60) {
          mybutton.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          mybutton.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    });

    function topFunction() {
      document.body.scrollTop = 0;
      document.scrollTop = 0;
      document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
```

Comment: still same issue, your code works great with online editors but locally nope. Even tested from my mobile still same issue

Comment: ```window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    console.log('Scrolled');
});``` not Even This Working